# delay in delay javascript looping

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, delay

I have a loop that already has a delay like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    setTimeout( function (i) {
        console.log("Hai")
    }, 1000*i, i);
}
```

if using coding above it will be executed with a 1 second pause for 100 repetitions

here I want to add one more delay where if it reaches 5 times it will pause longer eg 30 seconds then continue again before the delay

example :

```
Hai .. delay 1 second
Hai .. delay 1 second
Hai .. delay 1 second
Hai .. delay 1 second
Hai .. delay 1 second
delay 30 second 
Hai .. delay 1 second
Hai .. delay 1 second
Hai .. delay 1 second
Hai .. delay 1 second
Hai .. delay 1 second
```

Is that possible?

Comment: That is so bad way of doing it, you should use a single counter instead of running 100 instances. See `setInterval()`

Comment: `i >= 5 ? 30000 + 1000*i : 1000*i`

Comment: i need every 5 times not first 5 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const timeout = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
async function sayHai() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      await timeout(1000);
      console.log("Hai");
      if ( (i%5) == 4 ) await timeout(30000);
  }
}
```

Comment: what if for synchronous? , because this is intended for the console so I need syncronus sequentially

Comment: Just drop the "async"?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, without promises.

```
let i = 1
function timeout(){
    i++
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("Hai")
        timeout()
    },i % 5 === 0 ? 30000 : 1000)
}
timeout()
```

Comment: Is there a relation between the question and your answer?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille what?

Comment: After your edit, it's a lot better.  But the OP asks for an extra pause of 30 seconds, every 5 iterations.  You replace the 1 second pause by the 30 second one, which is not what is asked.  Moreover, you never stop, while the OP stops after 100 iterations.

Comment: And your code is not even working.
You forgot to call `sayHai()` and even when its called, there is a delay of 30 seconds after the first `console.log`

Comment: Corrected.  But sayHai may be called when needed.